# Postgres transaction and moving a row

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, transactions

I have a tableA and I need to delete a row in it but I want a backup log of that deleted row so I'll insert it into tableB fist like so (table A and B are the same)

```
DO $$
BEGIN
   Insert into tableB select * from tableA where (extract(epoch from (now() - keepalivedate))) > 120;
   Delete from tableA where (extract(epoch from (now() - keepalivedate))) > 120;
END
$$;
```

My Question is what happens if I update Keepalivedate on another connection between the insert and the delete? To simulate I did this:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
   Insert into tableB select * from tableA where (extract(epoch from (now() - keepalivedate))) > 120;
    PERFORM pg_sleep(60);
   Delete from tableA where (extract(epoch from (now() - keepalivedate))) > 120;
END
$$;
```

and ran on a different connection:
       update tableA Set keepalivedate = now();

And what happened was that TableB got the record with the original time and tableA kept the record with the updated time. That breaks my log.

I am expecting that this insert delete will be call frequently but that the where should fail most of the time. I am also expecting that the update to keepalivetime happens as frequently.

My workarounds are to select the PK into a temp table and then run the insert and delete where id's in temptable OR

```
DO $$
BEGIN
   PERFORM Processid From docsadm.LicenceCount where (extract(epoch from (now() - keepalivedate))) > 120
           for update;
   Insert into tableB select * from tableA where (extract(epoch from (now() - keepalivedate))) > 120;
   Delete from tableA where (extract(epoch from (now() - keepalivedate))) > 120;
END
$$;
```

Or am I just making this to complicated and I should go with my original statement?

Comment: Chaining the two statements using `returning ...` is what you want.

Comment: Little more help? Tried:
Delete From tableA where id in (

Comment: Little more help? Tried:
Delete From tableA where id in ( insert into TableB (...) select (...) from tableA where (...) Returning id

with tmp as ( insert into ........ returning ID)
delete from tableA where id in (select id from tmp)

with tmp as (delete from tableA where (...) returning * ) 
insert into tableB select (....) from tmp

Comment: `WITH zzz AS ( insert into history(...) SELECT ... FROM original where ... returning *) DELETE FROM original del WHERE EXISTS (select * FROM zzz where zzz.keyfields = del.keyfields);`

Comment: looks like part of my problem is version  9.0 other wise 7.8.2. Data-Modifying Statements in WITH should have worked